# Leetcode: why it behaviors different for ``at`` method for **string Class** on **Submit** and **Run Code**

Tags: c++

I am doing a problem on leetcode. The description of this problem is as follows:

Given a string **s** , find the length of the longest substring **t**  that contains at most 2 distinct characters.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: "eceba"
Output: 3
Explanation: t is "ece" which its length is 3.
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: "ccaabbb"
Output: 5
Explanation: t is "aabbb" which its length is 5.
```

I tried to do some comparison before I used the `at` method.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstringTwoDistinct(string s)
    {
        if (!s.length() || s.length() == 1 || s.length() == 2)
            return s.length();

        unsigned int left = 0, right = 0; // Use sliding window

        map<char, int> mp;

        int count;

        int len = s.length();

        int res = 1; // default answer

        while (right < len) {
            if (right < len && (mp.find(s.at(right)) == mp.end() || mp[s.at(right)] == 0)) {
                count++;
            }
            mp[s.at(right)]++;
            right++;

            if (count > 2) // if count is out of scope, just undo last action
            {
                count--;
                right--;
                if (right < len)
                    mp[s.at(right)]--;

                if (right - left > res) {
                    res = right - left;
                }

                while (count == 2) {
                    mp[s.at(left)]--;
                    if (mp[s.at(left)] == 0)
                        count--;
                    left++;
                }
            }
        }

        return right - left > res ? right - left : res;
    }
};
```

Since all the inputs must be valid.

My problem is that for input `aac`, I clicked the **Run Code** button, it works fine.

However, when I click **Submit**, it will fail on this case. Actually I bumped into this problem several times. I just want to know whether it is a compiler problem?

Comment: the link you provided requires an account

Comment: How does it fail? Compile error? To slow? What's the error message? The difference between run and submit is the number and complexity of test cases. The former only tests some simpler cases. The latter test complex cases.

Comment: Hint: initialise your variables.

Comment: @fdan I am sorry, I just noticed that this problem is open to premium user only, I just get a snapshot of it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please insert all necessary information as text into your question. Don't use links or images

Comment: @ThomasSablik the error is **Run Time Error**, it says that **throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at_n __n >= this->size()**, which confused me a lot. I listened to the your next door's suggestion and initialize `count`, it works.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks bro. It works. So the error message is actually misleading, right? it says that **throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at_n __n >= this->size(),**

Comment: @ThomasSablik I have inserted all the descriptions. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: "*I just want to know whether it is a compiler problem?*" The sooner you'll learn, the better. First Programming Rule says: **It is always your fault.** Or at least in 99.9% of the cases. Whenever you want to blame environment, compiler, or anyone else, you should stop and think: "It worked for thousands of people before me."

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you for your advice. As a novice, I cannot connect the error message to undefined behaviour now.I will keep your words. Btw,  I felted sorry for those who wasted their time because of my unclear description.

Comment: That was a bit of a joke, but most of programmers fall into the trap of blaming everything else for their code. It's a lesson everyone reapplies every now and then, when after digging everywhere for the solution for 3 days they find out the bug was a typo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to initialise the variable `count`, so your program has undefined behaviour.